# get request to the S3 bucket using aws lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

Hi need some help with using lambda functions...im trying to get a json file from the S3 bucket and here my code so far but it doesn't seem to work and idk how to proceed

````
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
exports.handler = async (event) => {

if(event.httpMethod === 'GET'){

    return getImage(event);
} 
if(event.httpMethod === 'POST'){
    return postImage(event);
} 
};    

async function getImage(filename) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: "artistimagestorage",
    Key: "savedImage.json",

  };

  const response = await s3.getObject(params, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)// handle errors
    }
  });
  return JSON.stringify(response.body)
} ```

all i got back from the api response is Endpoint response body before transformations: null
````

Comment: Could you try to chain `.promise()` after your `getObject` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the callback from the getObject call and promisify it instead.

```
const response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
```

Wrap the whole thing in a try catch block if you want to log errors.